# Schedule a meeting (UCWA). Service does not allow a cross domain request from this origin

Tags: c#, cross-domain, skype, skype-for-business, ucma

I am trying to schedule a meeting in Skype for Business. I have followed steps as:

https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/KeyTasks-OnlineMeeting-ScheduleMeeting

But my request is rejected. Reason for rejection from server is :

> Service does not allow a cross domain request from this origin.

I am confused on what should be my "X-ms-origin".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the following link pertains to UCWA and not UCMA, I believe this is the same issue:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn323658(v=office.16).aspx

Your domain needs to be configured in the allowed list for your web service configuration.  An example could be:

```
$x = New-CsWebOrigin -Url "https://example.com"
Set-CsWebServiceConfiguration -Identity "Global" -CrossDomainAuthorizationList @{Add=$x}
```

If you've created a web service configuration other than "Global", you can use that one instead.  Essentially, the domain where the request is originating from is not authorized.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I am trying to run skype wedsdk samples locally in windows. How to do this ? could you please provide more details.